# How can I find and replace specific text in a SAS data set?

Tags: replace, sas, dataset

I have a data set with 400 observations of 4 digit codes which I would like to pad with a space on both sides

```
ex. Dataset 
obs code
1   1111 
2   1112
3   3333
.
.
.
400 5999
```

How can I go through another large data set and replace every occurrence of any of the padded 400 codes with a " ".

```
ex. Large Dataset
obs text 
1   abcdef 1111 abcdef
2   abcdef 1111 abcdef 1112 8888
3   abcdef 1111 abcdef 11128888
...
```

Data set that I want

```
ex. New Data set
obs text
1   abcdef   abcdef
2   abcdef   abcdef   8888
3   abcdef   abcdef 11128888
...
```

Note: I'm only looking to replace 4 digit codes that are padded on both sides by a space. So in obs 3, 1112 won't be replaced.

I've tried doing the following proc sql statement, but it only finds and replaces the first match, instead of all the matches.

```
proc sql;  
    select   
    *,  
    tranwrd(large_dataset.text, trim(small_dataset.code), ' ') as new_text  
from large_dataset  
    left join small_dataset  
    on findw(large_dataset.text, trim(small_dataset.code))
;
quit;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you want to do if you encounter something like `abc111112abc` which has two matching 4-digit codes but can only match either one of them? What if you have something like `abc00111100abc` where you've got a match in the middle of a run of digits?

Comment: @user667489 I've edited my question so that I would never encounter an issue with the 2 situations you mentioned. I updated my original post to include what i've tried doing.

Comment: With only 400 strings of 4 bytes each you might be able to construct regular expression to replace them all on one function call.  SAS string variables are limited to 32K bytes.

Comment: @Tom Would love to learn this other method of creating a regular expression to solve this. I tried doing a proc sql with a long "where text not contains code1 .. or text not contains code2..." clause. But I couldn't figure out how to iterate through my list of 400 codes and pull out the code and append it to the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a DO loop to scan through the small dataset of codes for each record in the large dataset.  If you want to use `TRANWRD()` function then you will need to add extra space characters.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  length code $4 ;
  do i=1 to nobs while (text ne ' ');
    set codes(keep=code) nobs=nobs point=i ;
    text = substr(tranwrd(' '||text,' '||code||' ',' '),2);
  end;
  drop code;
run;
```

The DO loop will read the records from your CODES list. Using the POINT= option on the SET statement lets you read the file multiple times. The WHILE clause will stop if the TEXT string is empty since there is no need to keep looking for codes to replace at that point.

If your list of codes is small enough and you can get the right regular expression then you might try using `PRXCHANGE()` function instead.  You can use an SQL step to generate the codes as a list that you can use in the regular expression.

```
proc sql noprint ;
  select code into :codelist separated by '|'
  from codes
;
quit;

data want ;
  set have ;
  text=prxchange("s/\b(&codelist)\b/ /",-1,text);
run;
```

Comment: When you're reading a dataset many times like that, a `sasfile` statement might improve performance.

Comment: SASFILE might help, but a file with only 400 observations of 4 bytes each will probably already be buffered by the OS or SAS disk buffer.

Comment: Wow thank you! I think it worked. I'm still new to SAS and I don't quite understand why or how this code eliminates ALL occurrences of the 4 digit codes in each observation. Could someone explain?

Comment: Sorry, one more question.. why did you concatenate a ' ' to text in the line "text = substr(tranwrd(' '||text,' '||code||' ',' '),2);" ?  Shouldn't there be a ' ' concatenated to the other side of text too? 

like   

`text = substr(tranwrd(' '||text||' ',' '||code||' ',' '),2);`

Comment: `TRANWRD()` is a simple tool that just matches exactly what you tell it. To be able to match a code that appears at the beginning of the TEXT string you need to put a space before it.  Without that extra space before TEXT then it would not match since you are searching for spaces on both sides of the string.  You might also want to add one to the end, but that is less likely to be an issue since it would only be a problem if the TEXT string completely filled the defined length of the variable.  SAS character variables are always padded with spaces to their full defined length.

Comment: Thank you @Tom. Also, what is the purpose of `length code $4.`? Code is already a variable in the codes dataset. But this line seems to be defining a new variable that's also named "code" and I don't see anything being set to that new variable.

Comment: I added that because I was worried that you might have defined CODE as length $8 instead of length $4.  If so then the tranwrd() function call would be look for a code with 5 trailing spaces in stead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient ways of doing this, but this seems to work fairly well:

```
/*Create test datasets*/
data codes;
input code;
cards;
1111 
1112
3333
5999
;
run;

data big_dataset;
infile cards truncover;
input text $100.;
cards;
abcdef 1111 abcdef
abcdef 1111 abcdef 1112 8888
abcdef 1111 abcdef 11128888
;
run;

/*Get the number of codes to use for array definition*/
data _null_;
    set codes(obs = 1) nobs = nobs;
    call symput('ncodes',nobs);
run;

%put ncodes = &ncodes;

data want;
    set big_dataset;
    /*Define and populate array with padded codes*/ 
    array codes{&ncodes} $6 _temporary_;
    if _n_ = 1 then do i = 1 to &ncodes;    
        set codes;
        codes[i] = cat(' ',put(code,4.),' '); 
    end;
    do i = 1 to &ncodes;
        text = tranwrd(text,codes[i],' ');
    end;
    drop i code;
run;
```

I expect a solution using `prxchange` is also possible, but I'm not sure how much work it is to construct a regex that matches all of your codes compared to just substituting them one by one.

Comment: No need for the `data _null_` step or the array. Just use add `NOBS=NOBS` and `POINT=I` in the `set codes` statement so that you can just use one DO loop.

Comment: I prefer to read the codes dataset just once and store it in memory, as the disk I/O is then O(n + m) rather than O(n * m).

Answer (score 0):

Taking Tom's solution and putting the code-lookup into a hash-table. Thereby the dataset will only be read once and the actual lookup is quite fast. If the Large Dataset is really large this will make a huge difference.

```
data want ;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    length code $4 ;
    declare hash h(dataset:"codes (keep=code)") ; 
    h.defineKey("code") ;
    h.defineDone() ;
    call missing (code);
    declare hiter hiter('h') ;
  end;
  set big_dataset ;

  rc = hiter.first() ;
  do while (rc = 0 and text ne ' ') ;
    text = substr(tranwrd(' '||text,' '||code||' ',' '),2) ;
    rc = hiter.next() ;
  end ;
  drop code rc ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array and regular express:

```
proc transpose data=codes out=temp;
var code;
run;

data want;
if _n_=1 then  set temp;
array var col:;
set big_dataset;
do over var;
text = prxchange(cats('s/\b',var,'\b//'),-1,text);
end;
drop col:;
run;
```